# Scraping json field with similar/same name

Tags: python, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCJCI.png)I have two fields named the same (ish). When I am scraping, I keep returning the value of the amountusdcents, but i just need the value for 'amount'.

I have added am image of the text in json viewer of as it's easier.

[{"sizeOption":{"presentation":"3.5","value":3.5},"shoeCondition":"new_no_defects","boxCondition":"good_condition","lowestPriceCents":{"currency":"GBP","amount":25764,"amountUsdCents":31294},"instantShipLowestPriceCents":{"currency":"GBP","amount":34686,"amountUsdCents":42051},"lastSoldPriceCents":{"currency":"GBP","amount":18200,"amountUsdCents":22000},"stockStatus":"single_in_stock"},{"sizeOption":

```
        for entry in output:
            if (entry['shoeCondition'] == "new_no_defects") and (entry['boxCondition'] == "good_condition"):
                size = entry['sizeOption']['presentation']
                try:
                    price_cents = entry['lastSoldPriceCents']['amount']
                except KeyError:
                    price_cents = 'OOS!'
                results.append((size, price_cents))
```

You can ignore the first parts and just focus on price_cents = ...

expected results = 18200 , result I get = 22000

It's not grabbing the right value. Any ideas please?

Comment: Please post the json you are querying in text format.

Comment: I also don't see the path "sizeOption.presentation" in the Image you posted

Comment: As mentioned, you can ignore all the price and only focus on 'price cents = entry[...'

that all works fine.  I just can't grab the first 'amount' it grabs the 'amountusdcenbts' each time

Comment: Ok so you are querying the path "lastSoldPriceCents.amount" which is equal to 18200. I don't see why your execution gets 31294. It is the value from "lowestPriceCents.amountUsdCents". However you expect the value from "lowestPriceCents.amount". So why don't you just do `price_cents = entry['lowestPriceCents']['amount']` ?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated - wrong value

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result (`18200`) is the value of `entry.lastSoldPriceCents.amount`, I think your code works:

```py
price_cents = entry['lastSoldPriceCents']['amount']
```

Comment: sorry - mistyped, should be good now